# Firestore: Clients and invoices, how to model it

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following schema and I am not sure how to model it in Firestore.

I will be having clients and invoices. Clients "has" invoices. I need to be able to do these 2 queries:

- Show invoices that a client has
- Update all invoices in the system (change a boolean attribute from true to false).

What would be the right way to model this? The first query is satisfied by having a collection of clients with subcollection of their invoices. But the second one is satisfied by having a collection of all invoices?

Any experienced help is appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have another recommendation which involves you to create two top level collections like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- userId (documents)
   |          |
   |          --- //user details
   |
   --- invoices (collection)
         |
         --- invoiceId (documents)
              |
              --- yourBooleanProperty: true
              |
              --- userId: true
```

As you can see, the simplest way to achieve this, is to have a single collection named `invoices` that can hold as documents all the invoices in your database. Because a single invoice can belong only to a single user, you can have the `userId` as a property. To get all the invoices that correspond to a specific user, I recommend you to use the following query:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query query = rootRef.collection("invoices").whereEqualTo(userId, true);
```

And if you want to change the boolean property of all invoices from `true` to `false` at once, simply use the following query:

```
Query query = rootRef.collection("invoices").whereEqualTo(yourBooleanProperty, true);
```

Comment: Interesting. That is really smart. See Alex, this is my issue usually. If  I was thinking about the first requirement only then  I would've put collection of users with subcollection of invoices. Then let's say down the line , I get the second requirement, then that would mean a huge change to the code and the structure + migration of live data. Is this expected cost of NoSql /firestore?

Comment: This is the reverse lookup that allows you to query your database more easily. Yes it is expected because [Firestore pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) model is based on read/write operations. So depends on how much data you have at the time of migration.

Comment: By cost, I am referring to the cost of development involved to make the changes. Meaning you have to change the full structure and the way you do queryying and then migrate/normalize the data just because you got the second requirement at a later point. It seems firebase nosql model is good only if you know all the requirements ahead of time with very little future new queries.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. It doesn't matter in what language you are coding or what kind of database you are using, it would be ideal to have all the requirements in the first place but we all know this is not possible because all the time new requirements appear. Regarding the cost of development involved to make this kind of changes, it's worth if you reduce the cost or speed for your app. So it's up to you to decide if this is better for you. Cheers!

Comment: It just occured to me. Let's say the userdetails has a last name. How you would do "Get the the Last Name of the user who has an invoiceId of xyz" ? I am asking this to try to create logic on how to adapt evolving scenarios (the thinking logic). Let me know if you prefer me to ask this as a new question

Comment: It would be more appropriate. Send me a link, so I can take a look at it.

Comment: Here is the link for the related question....   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964755/firestore-clients-and-invoices-amended-requirement

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Firestore uses a document-oriented NoSQL model, similar to MongoDB and CouchDB, which leads to fundamentally different data structuring decisions.

You can think this structure in a relational way, and you can achieve the same results.

And you already did that here

> The first query is satisfied by having a collection of clients with
>   subcollection of their invoices.

so in order to solve your last requirement i would make a collection with all the invoices and then share with the clients invoice the current invoice id, so you will have inside your first query a subcollection with the ids to refer to your all invoices, this way you can refer to them and make any changes you want just querying the first collection.

let me just illustrates how they can connect

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but with this solution , I have to take each invoice id seperatly and query the db to get the details which defeats the requirement of changing boolean for all invoices (req 2)