# Firestore clients and invoices, amended requirement

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This question is a follow up question to the one posted here:

[Firestore: Clients and invoices, how to model it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867267/firestore-clients-and-invoices-how-to-model-it/50872325)

I am trying to understand the thought process behind modelling evolving requirements in Firebase/Firestore.

Assuming the accepted answer was used for the model, then 2 months you get a new requirement after the app has been released. Now the requirement says:
We need to get the invoice detail (not only id but the full details) for user whose last name is xyz.

How can model this assuming the database/app has been live for 2 months (so there is data in there already). The last name is already an attribute of the user details.

Thank you

Comment: Assuming that both requirements, `Show invoices that a client has` and `Update all invoices in the system to false` are mandatory, I'll modify the schema accordingly, just by adding a new property called `userId`, to each invoice object.

Comment: @AlexMamo Can you post that as an answer with a brief example of that structure? I would like to upvote it as It's relevant and provides excellent information for future readers.

Comment: Thank you @Jay for your appreciation! Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the requirements that we see in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867267/firestore-clients-and-invoices-how-to-model-it/50872325), which I understand are mandatory in your project:

> Show invoices that a client has

and

> Update all invoices in the system to false

The most appropriate schema that can I recommend you, is the one in which you should add a new property called `userId`, beneath each `invoice` object.

So please consider using this tehnique, which is actually called a the reverse lookup. It will help you query your database more easily and will also help you solve both problems.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for the answer. So if I am given last name, then I need to query the user table to get user ID and then do another query with user ID to query invoice details? Right? I mean the query I asked for can not be done in one call

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You cannot do this with a single query.

Comment: do you mind checking out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127386/firestore-db-model-attribute-in-document-or-subcollection

Comment: @Snake Sure, I'll take a look.